# Any examples how the software industry uses the Mathematica in production?

Tags: reference-request

Many researchers prototype the algorithms in Mathematica. I know the Mathematica is great for doing the scientific research. But what about the software industry?

Do you know some companies that use the Mathematica as part of its software/technology stack in production?

Comment: One example: Mathematica was used during the design of SimCity (not sure which version).  You'll find some info if you google for it.

Comment: Although many corporations have IT departments, I don't recognize anything that can be called an IT industry. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: You might want to look at the [WRI customer stories page](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/customer-stories/)

Comment: @m_goldberg: I mean the companies which staple is the software, technologies (or stack of them). I do not want to consider the companies those produce the research papers, simulation results, academicware or something like that.

Comment: The Q&A format of this site is designed for more specific, well-defined questions that solve actual problems encountered in the use of the software. This question doesn't seem to fit that format.